# Sending the iphone camera captured images to the web service and getting response?

Tags: iphone

Hey guys I was wondering if anyone had some sample code for enabling the camera for the iphone. I want to be able to Send the captured image to webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UIImagePickerController` and its `delegate` method will help you to get the image from camera which you can use.

Reference
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

Pls refer this also

[How to send images to a web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656604/how-to-send-images-to-a-web-service)

Comment: Sending the captured image to webservice how we can do that?

Comment: i am not getting it anywhere how to send the iphone camera captured image to an webservice

Comment: you can get the image from the delegate methods which u can save it as an UIImage or NSData and then you can use it to send to the web service

Comment: Can you please provide me some sample code for it or some sample app