# Is It Possible to send Image through Web service?

Tags: iphone, web-services, coldfusion

I Have made application in `iphone` which consume `coldfusion webservice.` I want to display Image on iphone application which is laid on remote server.Using `coldfusion webservice` I can retrieve Image from remote server.so I want to send that image to the iphone application through webservice.so Is It possible?Please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes , You can refer:[sending image via web][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216988/sending-the-iphone-camera-captured-images-to-the-web-service-and-getting-respons

Comment: I have referred but I want to send image from webservice to iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cffile or cfimage to read in the file.  Base64 encode the data then send it in the webservice.  In the iPhone app base64 decode an you will have the binary of the image.

Comment: I have tried this code but it doesnt give any output           <cfset imagePath = "C\abc.jpg">
<cffile action="read" file= "#imagePath#"  variable="myFile">
<cfset myFile=ToBase64(myFile)>
<cfoutput>#myFile#</cfoutput>

Answer (score 1):

Paul was on the right track.  However, you will more than likely need to read the source file differently.  From what I have found in the past you need to get the binary of the file and base64 that.  So, this code should work for you..

```
<cfset myFile = toBase64(fileReadBinary('path.to.image.file'))>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can upload image by creating form try below code

```
-(void)UploadImage{

NSString *urlString = @"yourUrl";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// file
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self scaleAndRotateImage:[selectedImageObj]],90);


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"user_photo\"; filename=\"photoes.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n",@"ImageNmae"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// close form
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// set request body
[request setHTTPBody:body];
//return and test
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  }
```

Comment: I dont want to upload image. I just want to display image which is laid on remote server which is retrieve by webservice .SO coldfusion webservice contain the image and that image I want to send the iphone apps which is to be displayed